# How can I change the snapping?

Tags: modeling, snapping, units

I put snapping on, but would like to snap objects with increments of .6 meters(60 cm). is there a way to change the snapping? I am working with lego bricks I brought in from Ldraw. Since ldraw automaticaly snaps to lego increments I need to change the snapping increments in blender.

Answer (score 3):

The new "absolute" snapping mode in 2.76 should do the trick. Press <kbd>n</kbd>, look in Display, set the grid scale to what you need, and it'll snap to wherever the grid is.

Hope that helps!

http://oneminutevideotutorials.com/absolute-grid-snapping-in-blender-2-76/